# mysqli_num_rows in PHP returns boolean given

Tags: php, mysqli

I’m not sure where is the problem is to fix this:

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given

Here is the function:

```
 public function checkUS($US){
        if(isset ($_POST['submit'])){
            $detailsCheck = mysqli_query($this->objDbConn,"SELECT Username FROM * WHERE Username='$US'");
            $numRows = mysqli_num_rows($detailsCheck);


            if(!$numRows >=1){
                echo "<span id='errors'>This username is been use</span>";
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `$this->objDbConn` is false b/c you have some kind of connection error.  You haven't given us the relevant code, but if you check the documentation you'll see where a boolean is returned.

Answer (score 3):

`$detailsCheck` is not a valid query. You might be missing `$US`, you might have your query wrong or not have permissions to run it... but....

I am pretty sure that this:

```
SELECT Username FROM * WHERE Username='$US'"
```

is meant to be this:

```
SELECT * FROM Username WHERE Username='$US'"
```

If the query you run isn't valid, then you can't run `mysqli_num_rows` on it - hence the error message *Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given* meaning that `$detailsCheck` is currently false, which in turn means that `mysqli_query` returned false - ie didn't work.

Edit: To troubleshoot code, output as much info as you can. See where code stops working, throw out error and warning messages wherever you can. Add some [error reporting](https://www.php.net/mysqli_error) to your `objDbConn` function. Track it down and sniff it out, I wager there is a good chance that when you see the error message you can solve it yourself without even thinking :)

Comment: so how can I make it to true? and I still have the warning after i change to SELECT * FROM Username WHERE Username='$US'"

Comment: @noooooooo You don't want it as a `TRUE` you want it as a resource. The easiest way to determine *where* your code is going wrong is to enable [errors](http://au2.php.net/mysqli_error) which you can then use to pinpoint where the problem is. Without something specific, folks here can only guess at the problem - and that's not a good way to troubleshoot anything. See additional edit in answer.